# What caused this yellow speckles and shrinking?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, indoors

The plant is Arabian Jasmine Sambac.

Is this caused by too much heat? Ambient temp in Delhi these days is 43C

This was growing all fine. It developed numerous green buds and was growing just like a perfect plant. It also bloomed 2-3 times. But for the past two weeks, the leaves are browning (old and new) and yellow spots have taken over. Also, some leaves are like drying. So I suspect it is the high temps and heat that is causing this.

This was placed in the south part of home with direct lighting (for a few minutes) and bright indirect lighting.

I am watering this plant when the soil gets dry to touch. I will rule out the soil because of m history here and for the fact that this plant is in this soil for months and it has grown from a tiny plant to this giant plant in the same pot. Also, no root issues :)

Same thing is happening with my Lemon Plant. Leaves are becoming crunchy.

[image]

Comment: Did you give it any fertilizer recently? I wonder if it got too much of something.

Comment: @Shule I gave it two months back :)